# Improvement in execution time by adding automatic variables

Tags: c, performance

I was playing with the C language on my own and I was trying to write the fastest possible algorithm to find [amicable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers).

This is what I wrote (I've just started, so please do not suggest me methods to improve the algorithm, since I want to write it on my own):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX (200000)

int dividersSum(int);
void amicable();

int main() {
    clock_t start = clock();
    amicable();
    double executionTime = ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nEXECUTION TIME: %lf", executionTime);
    return 0;
}

int dividersSum(int n) {
    int i, sum;
    for (sum = 1, i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (!(n % i)) {
            sum += n / i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void amicable() {
    int a, divSum, tot = 0;

    for (a = 1; a < MAX; a++) {
        divSum = dividersSum(a);
        if (divSum > a && dividersSum(divSum) == a) {
            printf("\n\t%d\t\t%d", a, dividersSum(a));
            tot++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nTOT: %d", tot);
}
```

Now, this works fine. Or, at least, probably not that fine since it took exactly 40 seconds to complete, but it works.

But if I change this line:

```
int i, sum;
```

Into this:

```
int i, sum, a = 4, b = 4, c = 4, d = 4, e = 4, f = 4;
```

It "drastically" improves. It takes 36 seconds to complete.

I get these execution times from the console timer. I know it isn't accurate at all (indeed as soon as I have the chance to work on this algorithm again I'll try to use `time.h` library), but I tried the 2 versions of the code over 50 times, and I always get 40 or more seconds for the "normal" version, and 36 or less for the other one.

I've also tried to change the machine where I run the program, but it always takes about 10% less to execute the modified version.

Of course this make no sense to me (I'm pretty new to programming, and I've Googled it but nothing even because I don't really know what to look for...), the only thing I can think about is an optimization of the compiler (I use the hated Dev c++), but which optimization? And if this is the case, why doesn't it use the same optimization also in the "normal" code, since it makes it faster?

---

Oh, if you're wondering why I tried to declare random variables, the reason is that I wanted to test if there was a measurable worsening in using more variables. I now know it is a very stupid way to test this, but as I said at the beginning of the post, I was "playing"...

Comment: You see, there are sites like [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3ntUFz) which let you compare assembly output of such programs. And there is no difference in between your programs in assembly output when using gcc compiler. So post the generated assembly of your programs, we can then compare them. Right now, you are comparing your compiler, not programs. What compiler and compiler options are using? Can you post the assembly of both programs?

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the answer! I can and I'll do it as soon as I can work on it again, but I don't understand how can I get the assembly. I mean, if I just need to copy the code I've posted on the site you suggested, I think it is what you've already done. By the way I use Dev c++ and I haven't changed any option.

Comment: Now read about register variables.

Comment: @i486 I've just read about them. What I've understood is that you can tell the compiler to put an often-used variable on a quick access register instead of in the default memory. I've also understood that you shouldn't use that keyword anymore, since the compiler optimize things better than you (or at least better than me). So you're saying that, since there are a lot of variables in the "faster" version of my code, the compiler puts the most used one on a register? Whereas in the "slower" one it doesn't do this beacuse there isn't a "most used" variable?Sorry if I misunderstood what you meant

Comment: 99.9% of the time, if not more, the `register` keyword is irrelevant.  The compiler will almost certainly ignore it and make its own optimization decisions.  The only difference is that you can't take the address of a register variable.  So, now you've read about `register`, you can forget it again.  All IMNSHO, of course.  (Your result — adding 6 unused variables reduces the time — is curious.  What platform are you using?  Are you using the same compiler options for both compilations?)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I haven't changed any option.  Yesterday I used the debug configuration, but I switched back to release. It seems very strange to me too, this is why I'm asking. I mean it is not a big issue, but I'd like to know why things like this happens, I'm very curious now! Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks for the answer, but how is this related to my question?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, 95% of all execution time questions with surprising results are caused by incorrect benchmarking. So it is fairly safe to bet this is the case here as well. Furthermore it is pointless to discuss speed without mentioning optimization settings.

Comment: Are you using release configuration to compile the programs and that is where you see the time differences? I would think that some compilers would completely ignore unused variables (also output warnings), at least with a release build. If the unused variables are taking up space, that could affect alignment, but in a release build, registers should be used for `i, n, sum` .

Comment: @Lundin You are right, indeed I added to te code a different method to get the execution time. But always same result. This is a very simple code, I think an error in benchmarking would be easy to spot. About what concerns compiler option, I use `TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release` configuration in Devc++ (which is the default). I haven't changed any other option.

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you for the answer. Yes, I use `TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release` configuration. As I've just written in my answer, my university teacher told me something similiar to what you said about register alignment. By the way, as you said, it is strange that the compiler does not discard unused variables.

Comment: Does "release" mean enable optimization or does it just mean leave out debug information? I haven't used Dev C++ in 15 years so I don't remember which gcc options it boils down to :)

Comment: @Lundin I checked and the option `Optimization level (-Ox)` is blank. So I think there are no optimization options activated.

Comment: If the compiler isn't ignoring (or warning about) unused variables (even though it's a relatively trivial optimisation), then the compiler is poo (either bad in general or crippled by command line options), and the answer to your question should be "the compiler is poo" (e.g. fails to optimise the second version into exactly the same output code as the first version).

Comment: @Brendan No, it doesn't throw warnings. I think yours is the best comment here. I've tried my code on an online compiler, and it takes the exact same time to run the 2 versions. Actually Devc++ is known to be a poo(r) compiler... I'll add and quote your comment in the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcoRossi If you run the code without optimizations, then discussing how to improve performance is obviously pointless.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not discussing how to improve performance. I wanted to know why that thing happened. Probably it's more related to a poor compiler than to optimization. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I asked my teacher at university. He ran the two versions on his machine, and he was fairly surprised at the beginning (43 seconds the "normal" one and 36 the faster).

Then he told me that he didn't know exactly why this happens, but he speculated that it happens due to the way the compiler organizes the code. Probably those extra variables force the compiler to store the code in different pages of the memory, and this is why this happens. 
Of course he wasn't sure about his answer, but it seems fair to me.

It's interesting how things like this can happen sometimes.

---

Moreover, as [Brendan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559737/brendan) said in the comments section:

> If the compiler isn't ignoring (or warning about) unused variables (even though it's a relatively trivial optimisation), then the compiler is poo (either bad in general or crippled by command line options), and the answer to your question should be "the compiler is poo" (e.g. fails to optimise the second version into exactly the same output code as the first version).

---

Of course if someone thinks to have a better explaination I would be happy to listen to him!

Comment: If Brendan had posted this answer, I would have upvoted it. What compiler, platform and settings are you using? I cannot reproduce your observations on OS/X with clang.